# How can I change an image once clicked to its other version repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making a simple project in HTML/CSS/JS. I want to make a light bulb turn on and off. I have both the images in the same directory, and so far I have been able to make it so that when I click on it it will turn off. But, after that, I can click it no more.

I want to be able to do this repeatedly, again and again, to turn it off, and then on again. Any ideas? I am trying to do this with no tutorials, I can't think of anything.

Here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Light Switch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
    <img src="light-on.png" onclick="this.src='light-off.png'">
    <img src="light-off.png" onclick="this.src='light-on.png'">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use Javascript.

Comment: Oh I already have found a solution thank you

Answer (score 1):

A working code can be created by your way, but it's inefficient and not elegant. You need only one img element and to change its source.

```
<img src="light-on.png" class="image--switchable" data-light="on">
```

You can use onclick in img tag, but I think event listener is a better solution.

```
let alternation = {
  on: "off",
  off: "on"
}

// I assume you have multiple images. That's why I used querySelectorAll and forEach.
document.querySelectorAll(".image--switchable").forEach(img => {
   img.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let light = img.dataset.light;
      img.src = `light-${alternation[light]}.png`
      img.dataset.light = alternation[light];
   })   
})

// If you have only one image use:
// document.querySelector(".image--switchable").addEventListener...
```

Comment: i actually solved the problem myself ... however I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript for the image to be changed

Comment: You do. I have figured I need to use an if statement.